# Where can I find instructions to copy R packages to CD

Tags: r

I need to install R packages on a computer that is unable to download from a CRAN. I would like to install packages from a local source to solve this issue. Where can I find instructions to copy R packages to CD so I can install them from a local source on another computer?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Is it: (1) How to download files from CRAN and then burn those as downloaded? (2) How to burn the already-installed packages on my hard drive to a CD? Frankly, it doesn't matter ... R has nothing to do with burning any files to a CD, is there a reason the CD-burn software isn't helping?

Comment: Presumably you could download the tar files and burn them like any other files.

Comment: I want to copy the installed packages from on computer using R to a CD. Then on another computer I would like to use that CD as the local source for the R packages in place of downloading them from A CRAN.  Does that help explain?

Comment: If the architecture and R-versions are identical between the two computers, then it is feasible to just copy the files to a CD just as one would do anywhere; this has nothing to do with R or RStudio. (Incidentally, you'll need to exit R on the air-gapped computer, then extract, then restart R.) If there are any differences in architecture or R-version, though, you should download each tarball individually from CRAN, burn onto a CD in the normal way, and then `install.packages("path/to/package.tar.gz", repos=NULL)` for each on the air-gapped machine. Regardless ... R is not involved in burning.

Comment: You can find details about installing packages in the manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html